# Is 4.8px font-size a minimum threshold for responsive value in CSS? (On Google Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, font-size

I was testing to check on the computed value of font-size using percentage (%). I am using chrome *(Version 78.0.3904.87)* on my environment.

I understand that the default font-size of my root element is 16px as I saw it inside my devTools. However, I am getting **4.8px computed font-size** when I applied **1% font-size on html** (root element).

So, I am wondering is 4.8px a magical number of some sort in Chrome or what? Can someone please enlighten me or point me to any relevant sources? Thanks in advance!

Below are my html and a screenshot of my devTools showing the computed font-size value of 4.8px

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    html{
      font-size: 1%
    }

    .test{
      font-size: 15rem
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test">Testing</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something less ambiguous? Such as creating an element with a set size then computing the size within it?  '%' is a relative style and could be referencing a value that's not 16px, like the size of the window.

Comment: Well, i have tried using 50% instead of 1% as the font-size value. The computed value was then 8px. So, 16px is my root element's default font-size for sure. I mean, even if I removed all styles and I check on the html tag's font-size, the computed value is 16px.

Comment: I ran the exact code you posted and got 10px.  I am running a different version of chrome but it's up to date.  I also tried resizing it and changing a bunch of properties with no change in the 10px.  UPDATE:  I moved the window to a different monitor and the computed style dropped to 6px.  My new best guess is it has something to do with painting the font to the screen based on resolution.

Comment: @HarrySaliba May I know what's the version of your Chrome? On my end, shifting to different screens and resizing did not make any difference

Comment: Version 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit) and its running on Ubuntu